# How many string object are created when using string concatenation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I'm a beginner in C#, just have some question on string concatenation.

```
string str = "My name is";
str += "John"
```

Q1-Does C#(.NET) have the same concept string pool in Java?

Q2- how many string object are created?

Comment: In *general*, if you want to understand the memory allocation behaviour of code, it's a better investment of your time to learn to use an appropriate *profiling* tool. Certainly better than trying to learn "all of the rules".

Answer (score 4):

> Q1-Does C#(.NET) have the same concept string pool in Java?

T̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶,̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶C̶#̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶p̶o̶o̶l̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶j̶a̶v̶a̶, each string is its own reference;

***Correction*** : I had to research this for Java...  It is  conceptually the same thing, i was mistaken about the details of Javas string pool

C# commonly calls it string interning

You can read more about it here at *Fabulous Adventures In Coding* : ***Eric Lippert's*** *Erstwhile Blog*

[String interning and String.Empty](http://%20https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/)

> If you have two identical string literals in one compilation unit then
>   the code we generate ensures that only one string object is created by
>   the CLR for all instances of that literal within the assembly. This
>   optimization is called "string interning".

String interning is a CLI feature that reuses a string instance in certain situations :

1. `string` literals, created via the `ldstr` *IL* command
2. When invoked explicitly using `string.Intern`

---

> Q2- how many string object are created?

Because strings in C# are immutable, you get 3 string allocations out of your 2 statements

```
// 1st string
string str = "My name is";

// 2nd string
// "John"

// 3rd string, which is the concatenation of the first 2
str += "John"
```

Comment: Unless the *optimizer* makes the concatenation of *two constants* at the *compile time*: and thus produces an equivalent of `string str = "My name isJoin;"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I'm not sure they would intern like that, also at least in this case the generated asm doesnt show this kind of optimisation. Worthy comment through

Comment: @DmitryBychenko that isn't done, though `string str = "My name is" + "John";` **is** complied as if it was `string str = "My name isJohn";`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a thing.

The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a particular value only exists once in the system. 
[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=netframework-4.7.2)

In your case, I believe there will be three allocations.